# Invalid Column Name Error after ALTER and UPDATE

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to UPDATE a specific column within a table, but I get an error due to the fact that when SQL compiles, the column name IssueTimeUTC does not actually exist. Here is my sample code:

```
   WHILE  @startissuetime<='23:30'
        BEGIN
        ALTER TABLE Intraday_Forecast_temp
            ADD IssueTimeUTC SMALLDATETIME 

            UPDATE Intraday_Forecast_temp
            SET IssueTimeUTC=CAST(@tempdate AS SMALLDATETIME)
            WHERE DateTimeUTC>CAST(@tempdate AS SMALLDATETIME)

            UPDATE Intraday_Forecast_temp
            SET IssueTimeUTC=Dateadd(d,-1,CAST(@tempdate AS SMALLDATETIME))
            WHERE
```

DateTimeUTC<=CAST(@tempdate AS SMALLDATETIME)
            END

I have read multiple similar posts, but I cannot make anything work therefore I am kindly asking you if you could help me.

The error I get is this:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 56 Invalid column name 'IssueTimeUTC'.

**Update:** So basically I was not able to find an exact solution to this specific problem but I just found a way to go ''around'' the problem instead. So this is the updated code I used.

```
WHILE  @startissuetime<='23:30'
    BEGIN
        ALTER TABLE Intraday_Forecast_temp
        DROP COLUMN IssueTimeUTC 
        --------
        BULK INSERT..... 
        --------
        ALTER TABLE Intraday_Forecast_temp
        ADD IssueTimeUTC SMALLDATETIME 

        UPDATE Intraday_Forecast_temp
        SET IssueTimeUTC=CAST(@tempdate AS SMALLDATETIME)
        WHERE DateTimeUTC>CAST(@tempdate AS SMALLDATETIME)

        UPDATE Intraday_Forecast_temp
        SET IssueTimeUTC=Dateadd(d,-1,CAST(@tempdate AS SMALLDATETIME))
        WHERE DateTimeUTC<=CAST(@tempdate AS SMALLDATETIME)
    END
```

I know that this is not probably the most elegant solution but I initially defined the Intraday_Forecast_temp table WITH the column IssueTimeUTC , then I drop it and add it again. This way, SQL stop complaining that the column does not exist upon compilation :)

Comment: Putng the `ALTER TABLE .. ADD COLUMN` inside a loop does not seem like a good idea ;)

Comment: Plus, I don't see how the `WHILE` loop is going to end. Do you want it to run forever?

Comment: Can you give a little more detail as to what exactly you're trying to achieve?Like, why are you trying to add a column multiple times? What is your current state, and what is your desired state (for the data)?

Comment: I am ending the WHILE loop by using an IF BREAK statement!

Answer (score 10):

You cannot add the column and use it **in the same batch**.

So if you execute your code in `SSMS` just add `GO` between your commands like this:

```
    ALTER TABLE Intraday_Forecast_temp
        ADD IssueTimeUTC SMALLDATETIME 

go ----------------------------<<<<<-----------------------------

        UPDATE Intraday_Forecast_temp
        SET IssueTimeUTC=CAST(@tempdate AS SMALLDATETIME)
        WHERE DateTimeUTC>CAST(@tempdate AS SMALLDATETIME)

        UPDATE Intraday_Forecast_temp
        SET IssueTimeUTC=Dateadd(d,-1,CAST(@tempdate AS SMALLDATETIME))
        WHERE DateTimeUTC<=CAST(@tempdate AS SMALLDATETIME)
```

If it's a part of `stored procedure`, wrap your `update` in `EXEC`:

```
exec ('UPDATE Intraday_Forecast_temp
        SET IssueTimeUTC=CAST(@tempdate AS SMALLDATETIME)
        WHERE DateTimeUTC>CAST(@tempdate AS SMALLDATETIME)')
```

**UPDATE**

In your case you can use wrapping in `exec` this way:

```
declare @tempdate date = getdate(); -- or whatever it should be
declare @sql nvarchar(4000)= N'UPDATE Intraday_Forecast_temp
        SET IssueTimeUTC=CAST(@tempdate AS SMALLDATETIME)
        WHERE DateTimeUTC>CAST(@tempdate AS SMALLDATETIME)';

exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@tempdate date', @tempdate = @tempdate;
```

Comment: I have tried that but it actually does not work, because my ALTER and UPDATE statements are within a WHILE loop. So if I add a GO in between, then I get an error that my variable @tempdate has not been declared

Comment: Please update your question with the code you want to execute. Of course the visibility of a variable is batch only,maybe you can genetare your values using sequence or fill the table with these values and then access them from your loop

Answer (score 0):

Just do this.

Execute first the `ALTER` statement

```
ALTER TABLE Intraday_Forecast_temp
    ADD IssueTimeUTC SMALLDATETIME
```

Have it executed successfully then execute the UPDATE statement.

```
UPDATE Intraday_Forecast_temp
SET IssueTimeUTC=CAST(@tempdate AS SMALLDATETIME)
WHERE DateTimeUTC>CAST(@tempdate AS SMALLDATETIME)

UPDATE Intraday_Forecast_temp
SET IssueTimeUTC=Dateadd(d,-1,CAST(@tempdate AS SMALLDATETIME))
WHERE DateTimeUTC<=CAST(@tempdate AS SMALLDATETIME)
```